# Git: Fixed merge conflict, but now there's no files to commit?

Tags: git, merge

I'm trying to merge and push a commit to a remote repo.

I got a merge error on 2 files and so fixed them.

I then `git status` and see:

```
Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#       both modified:  css/main.css
#       both modified:  sass/_style-guide.scss
```

Yep, those are the files I fixed, so I run: `git add .` then `git commit` but instantly get a message:

`You have no files to commit`

Would anyone know why this is behaving this way?

Comment: I'm not sure why but the `/` at the beginning of your paths looks fishy to me. Can you try running `git status` after your `git add` to check whether the files are actually staged and if not, explicitly `git add` them giving their names rather than just `.`.

Comment: Oops, sorry the `/` was my fault - I deleted the start of the path to save space above.

I tried `git status` straight after `git add .` and it appears nothing is being staged. Could it be that my fixes are making the files exactly like that on the remote repo?

Comment: Sometimes resolving merge conflicts results in auto-commit. Have a check on that too. And what exactly did you do to fix it?

Comment: @Dash - with the .scss there were simply some `@import` lines in different orders. I favored HEAD over mine with this. With the .css file I didn't look, just recompiled it with gulp. Presumably it was the same thing: just the .css the `@imports` brought in in different orders.

Comment: Correct me if my understanding is wrong. If you favoured HEAD-->Now you have an copy of HEAD with no local changes, is it correct?

Comment: It looks like `.` doesn't include the changed files possibly because you're in a sub directory. If you're at the repository root, `git add .` will work. Otherwise, you'll have to add the with full paths. And no, it's not because your files are exactly like those on the remote repository. A commit will still have to be done. Also, I'm not sure what kinds of resolutions result in an auto-commit. I've never seen that happen.

Comment: Edit : Since it was only import lines with different orders I presume git considers both HEAD & Local as same copies thus no commit required. If you are doubtful about this assumption, may try changing something else explicitly and check whether commit is as per expectation or not.